# Parse xml with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse a XML document with Python, this is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("aula.xml")

hosts = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("host")

for host in hosts:
    address = host.getElementByTag("address")
    ip = address.attributes["addr"]
    IP = ip.value
    print("IP:%s"%(IP))
```

this returns me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "simple.py", line 8, in <module>
address = host.getElementByTag("address")
AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute 'getElementByTag'
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 6.47 scan initiated Thu Feb 26 11:38:24 2015 as: nmap -oX aula.xml x.x.x.x/26 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -oX aula.xml x.x.x.x/26" start="1424947104" startstr="Thu Feb 26 11:38:24 2015" version="6.47" xmloutputversion="1.04">
  <scaninfo type="connect" protocol="tcp" numservices="1000" services="a lot of numbers"/>
  <verbose level="0"/>
  <debugging level="0"/>
  <host starttime="1424947104" endtime="1424947111"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
    <address addr="x.x.x.x" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <hostnames>
    </hostnames>
    <ports>
        <extraports state="closed" count="998">
            <extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="998"/>
        </extraports>
        <port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
        <port protocol="tcp" portid="111"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="rpcbind" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
    </ports>
    <times srtt="1280" rttvar="264" to="100000"/>
</host>
</nmaprun>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **No getElementByTag method:**: There is no such method. Use `getElementsByTagName()` method to get the `address` tag list.
2. Check if list have items or not then get `addr` attribute value from the address tag.
   3.

Demo:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

p = '/home/vivek/Desktop/Work/input_minidom.xml'
xmldoc = minidom.parse(p)

hosts = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("host")

for host in hosts:
    address = host.getElementsByTagName("address")
    if address:
        ip = address[0].attributes["addr"]
        IP = ip.value
        print("IP:%s"%(IP))
```

Output:

```
$ python task4.py 
IP:x.x.x.x
```

Comment: @CristinaNogués: Welcome. If you have any issue related to python you can ask on stackoverflow or I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.  If answer is helpful to you then you can up vote and accept answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to vote up your answer but it seems that I need to have 15 points reputation.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one `address`. So use

```
address = host.getElementsByTagName("address")[0]
```

to get the first `address`.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementByTag`. The return value is a list of tags matching, so you'll have to iterate through it. For instance:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("aula.xml")

hosts = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("host")

for host in hosts:
    addresses = host.getElementsByTagName("address")
    for address in addresses:
        ip = address.attributes["addr"]
        IP = ip.value
        print("IP:%s"%(IP))
```